# get_the_terms() to show all custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, post-meta, terms

I have created three custom taxonomies that categorize my post types by `project-client`, `project-brand`, & `project-medium`. As of now I can use the `get_the_terms()` function to return only one taxonomy successfully, `project-client`.

Is there a way to use `get_the_terms()` to show taxonomies from all three custom taxonomies or is a different function needed such as `get_terms()`?

My code as it stands:

```
<?php
$project_attrs = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'project-client' );
if (!empty($project_attrs)){ ?>
    <ul class="meta">
        <?php 
        foreach($project_attrs as $attr){
        echo '<li>' . $attr->name . ' ' . '/' . '</li>';
        }    
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

The function is successful at displaying my requested taxonomy, just would like to know how to display all taxonomies from multiple custom taxonomies.

Comment: You can get all the registered taxonomies with [`get_taxonomies()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies), then loop over that to get all the terms from all the taxonomies.

Comment: @Pat J Looked at get_taxonomies and it would give me the taxes of all public taxonomies so I continued reading up and managed to create an array of taxonomies to get the result I needed. Your comment helped me go in the right direction. Thank you. Here is the final code for reference: pastebin.com/N70ZABYV